# Alternative to global variable when using clearTimeout & setTimeout

Tags: javascript, redux

**EDIT**  *I used the wrong term in the title and question. I did not mean a global variable, but to instead declare `timeoutID` inside of the showNotification function.*

I'm on my first week of testing Redux. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant / less hacky solution to using a glodal variable for the timeoutID? clearTimeout is used to guarantee that the last added notification is always shown for the full desired time, even if it would be added before the previous notification was set to "empty".

actionCreator.js

```
import { addQuote } from "./addQuote"
import { showNotification } from "./showNotification"

export const actionCreator = (quote, time) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(addQuote(quote))
    dispatch(showNotification(quote, time))
  }
}
```

showNotification.js

```
let timeoutID = null

export const showNotification = (newQuote, time) => {

  const message = `A new quote by ${newQuote.author} was added.`
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', data: message })

    clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', data: '' })
    }, time * 1000)
    
  }
}
```

notificationReducer.js

```
const initState = {
  notification: ''
}

const notificationReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION':

    const message = action.data
      return {
        ...state,
        notification: message
      }

    default:
      return {
        ...state
      }
  }
}

export default notificationReducer
```

Comment: It's not global, it's a closure, and that's one of the core principles that make a module world work. If it were global you could use the variable in any other JS file without ever explicitly importing it. In `actionCreator.js` which does `import { showNotification } from "./showNotification"` try to `console.log(timeoutID)` and you'll get `undefined`. There is not only nothing wrong with programming this way; it's state of the art and in contrast to passing parameters around, a very elegant way to solve the problem.

Comment: I see, I used the wrong term. I meant, is it possible to declare timeoutID inside of the showNotification function.

Comment: Yes, just like it's being done with `message`. As with any closure, you just need to make sure the variable is in scope of the functions using them *at the time the functions are being declared*.

Comment: If I declare **timeoutID** inside the function like **message** and I would like to show the notifications for e.g. 5 seconds and add a new quote before the first notification clears, the second notification is only shown for the remainder of the "original" 5 seconds.  When **timeoutID** is declared outside the last added quote is always shown for the full desired time.

Comment: Ah, you're right, the reason is that every time you call `showNotifcations`, if you declare `timeoutId` inside of it, you create a new local variable. So in this case, if you only want one variable `timeoutId` to exist, you need to declare it outside, so it's only ever created at the time of importing the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just felt it was a bit hacky...

Answer (score 1):

It's **not** global, it's a ***closure***, and that's one of the core principles in a module world (which was invented to circumvent having to make use of the global namespace!).

If it *were* global you could use the variable in any other JS file without ever explicitly importing it.

In `actionCreator.js`, which does `import { showNotification } from "./showNotification"`, try to `console.log(timeoutID)` and you'll get `undefined`.

*Closures* are really nothing complicated; it just means that **any function when declared will "remember" any local variables that were known ("in scope" is the more technically correct term for "known") at the point of the function's declaration, no matter when the function is called, or who calls it**. Those variables known to a function via this mechanism are called *closures*.

There is not only nothing wrong with programming this way; it moreso is state of the art and in contrast to other far more verbose and lengthy solutions like passing parameters around, the most elegant way to solve the problem.